# Android app cannot update from playstore, after shareduserid removed from manifest

Tags: android

After remove android:sharedUserId="com.xx.xxx" from manifest not able to update app from playstore because application has changed.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid

**This constant was deprecated in API level 29.
Shared user IDs cause non-deterministic behavior within the package manager. As such, its use is strongly discouraged and may be removed in a future version of Android. Instead, apps should use proper communication mechanisms, such as services and content providers, to facilitate interoperability between shared components. Note that existing apps cannot remove this value, as migrating off a shared user ID is not supported**.

Unfortunately need to make uninstall and re-install only , How to make to Update app ?

Answer (score 0):

Added android:sharedUserId in LauncherManifest.xml is working fine now